# How deploy a smart contract with meteor and metamask?

Tags: contract-deployment, dapp-development, metamask, meteor

I will deploy a smart contract with meteor and matamask.
My code in `main.js` :

```
var inactivityTime = 1000;
var continuityContract = web3.eth.contract(Continuity.abi);
var continuity = continuityContract.new(
   inactivityTime,
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
     data: Continuity.bytecode,
     gas: 4700000
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

but I have this error

> Uncaught Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous
>   methods like eth_uninstallFilter without a callback parameter.

Any idea ?

Code is on github: https://github.com/n1c01a5/etherlife.co

Comment: Can't reproduce. Is this still a problem? Seems error message has nothing to do with contract creation. Maybe some other code causes it?

Comment: Yes I think metamask has fixed this issue :)

Answer (score -2):

There is a great series of tutorial I followed to deploy a meteor Dapp, that you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpUMn66UtRQ).

It's fairly recent, and when I had problems I left a comment and the author answered personally and helped me fix my mistakes. You should check it out.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.